# Why does the resistance of a tungsten filament level of at a certain temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, electrical-resistance

I have tungsten filament. When I apply a voltage and measure the current and calculate the resistance. I can see that the resistance of the filament increases over time (due to the increasing temperature). My measurements suggest that the final resistance after a sufficiently long time is (almost) independent of the voltage I apply i.e. it doesn't matter if I apply 4 V,5 V or 6 V after more than 60s it will reach about 0.23 Ohms.

What happens inside the tungsten filament that at first its resistance is highly dependent on temperature and at higher temperature almost independent of temperature?

**Edit: Honestly, I think I need to modify my setup a little bit. I have doubts about my measurements.**

Comment: I think your data space is incomplete.  Where have you verified that the **temperature** reached is different for those different applied voltages?  I suspect the rate of heat exchange, both conductive to air and radiative (Planck's Law) is radically different.    Not to mention you need to try at least 10,20,50,100 V to see what happens.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: It's difficult to measure the temperature directly because the filament is inside a vacuum tube (magnetron). However, if a certain amount of power is dissipated by the filament, I assume this will be converted to heat, e.g. 5V and 20 A is 100 Watts (or 6 V and 24 A  is 144 Watts) of heat. I assume that the glowing of the tube is a negligible compared to the heat transfer. To the second point: the filament isn't specified for these voltages. Absolute maximum is 6 V.

Comment: In my physics lab, we measured the resistance of a standard tungsten bulb from 10 to 110 volts.  It kept going up. (With a carbon filament bulb, it went down.)

Comment: @R.W.Bird: Interesting. Maybe I have to measure more carefully. I think if I squint I can still see an increase in resistance. However, the increase in resistance is very visible at lower temperature and then becomes smaller at higher temperatures. Why is that?